# iOS Safari Extension - Additional Permissions Requested banner

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I've developed iOS Safari extension and a little confused how extension, like Honey shows top  Additional Permissions Requested banner when user enables extensions and has to provide allow tracking web sites.

Manifest example

```html
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "default_locale": "en",

    "name": "Extension_name",
    "description": "Extension_desc",
    "version": "1.0",

    "icons": {
        "48": "images/icon-48.png",
        "96": "images/icon-96.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png",
        "256": "images/icon-256.png",
        "512": "images/icon-512.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
        "persistent": false
    },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "all_frames": true,
            "match_about_blank": true,
            "js": [ "***.js" ],
            "css": [ "***.css" ],
            "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
          },
        {
        "js": [ "content.js" ],
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
    }],

    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/toolbar-icon-16.png",
            "19": "images/toolbar-icon-19.png",
            "32": "images/toolbar-icon-32.png",
            "38": "images/toolbar-icon-38.png",
            "48": "images/toolbar-icon-48.png",
            "72": "images/toolbar-icon-72.png"
        }
    },

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "nativeMessaging",
    ]
}
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptQBJ.jpg)